# Does Canon's USA lens warranty hold in India?

Tags: lens, canon, legal

I have purchased a Canon lens in the USA from Amazon. Now I stay in India and am  planning to sell that lens. The lens is in warranty period. Does the warranty still hold in India? (Are all Canon lenses covered by an international warranty, unlike the camera bodies?)

In general, what does Canon mean by by International Warranty for cameras and for lenses?

Answer (score 4):

"International" might mean just USA+Canada - that's already two countries, so it's international. And that's how it's written in current [Canon EF Lenses Limited Warranty](http://www.usa.canon.com/app/pdf/support/warranty/warranty_EF_lenses.pdf) from Canon USA:

> The limited warranty set forth below is given ... with respect to the Canon
>   ... Photographic Lens Products ... when **purchased and used** in the **United
>   States or Canada**.

To make sure what terms apply to your lens, refer to the warranty documentation that came with your lens. If it says worldwide, India should be included. If your local service refuses to accept it, try contacting Canon USA to help arranging the service in your country.

Note that Canon has given the warranty to *you*, the original buyer, not the person you're selling the lens to; if they have data about your ownership, they [may refuse to transfer the warranty](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2277318#forum-post-27315194) to the second-hand buyer (who obviously won't be have gotten the lens from an authorized dealer).

Comment: _And used?_ Really? They won't cover problems that develop when traveling?

Comment: This is what they *oblige* to do; they might still actually cover problems that develop elsewhere... if they feel like it.

Comment: Wow. I just looked at the warranties for Pentax, Nikon, and Sony, and none of them have a similar clause limiting geographic use. I presume Canon doesn't attempt to enforce that very often, or else there would be quite a fuss about it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they changed their policy recently both Canon and Nikon only respect the warranty at the same country the equipment was bought in.

This includes everything: camera bodies, lenses, flashes, etc.

Update: more correctly, they only respect the warranty in country the equipment was sold for - for example, if you buy the European version (that is exactly the same as the US version) in the US you can only get service in Europe

Comment: what is meant by International Warranty

Comment: @anish you'll need to provide more context. Does the documentation with your lens include a specific reference to "international warranty"?